# Using index with IN clause and ordering by primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am having a problem with the following task using MySQL. I have a table Records(id,enterprise, department, status). Where id is the primary key, and enterprise and department are foreign keys, and status is an integer value (0-CREATED, 1 - APPROVED, 2 - REJECTED).

Now, usually the application need to filter something for a concrete enterprise and department and status:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE status = 0 AND enterprise = 11 AND department = 21
    ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0,10;
```

The order by is required, since I have to provide the user with the most recent records. For this query I have created an index (enterprise, department, status), and everything works fine. However, for some privileged users the status should be omitted:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE enterprise = 11 AND department = 21
    ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0,10;
```

This obviously breaks the index - it's still good for filtering, but not for sorting. So, what should I do? I don't want create a separate index (enterprise, department), so what if I modify the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE enterprise = 11 AND department = 21
      AND status IN (0,1,2)
    ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0,10;
```

MySQL definitely does use the index now, since it's provided with values of status, but how quick will the sorting by primary key be? Will it take the recent 10 values for each status available, and then merge them, or will it first merge the ids for each status together, and only after that take the first ten (this way it's gonna be much slower I guess).

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Also note that MySQL an only use 1 index per select. So, it cannot use 1 index for sorting and another one for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

All of the queries will benefit from one composite query:

```
INDEX(enterprise, department, status, id)
```

`enterprise` and `department` can swapped, but keep the rest of the columns in that order.

The first query will use that index for both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`, thereby be able to find the 10 rows without scanning the table or doing a sort.

The second query is missing `status`, so my index is less than perfect.  This would be better:

```
INDEX(enterprise, department, id)
```

At that point, it works like above.  (Note:  If the table is InnoDB, then this 3-column index is identical to your 2-column `INDEX(enterprise, department)` -- the PK is silently included.)

The third query gets dicier because of the `IN`.  Still, my 4 column index will be nearly the best.  It will use the first 3 columns, but not be able to do the `ORDER BY id`, so it won't use `id`.  And it won't be able to comsume the `LIMIT`.  Hence the `EXPLAIN` will say `Using temporary and/or Using filesort`.  Don't worry, performance should still be nice.

My second index is not as good for the third query.

See my [*Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/).

"How quick will sorting by id be"?  That depends on two things.

- Whether the sort can be avoided (see above);
- How many rows in the query *without* the `LIMIT`;
- Whether you are selecting `TEXT` columns.

I was careful to say whether the `INDEX` is used all the way through the `ORDER BY`, in which case there is no sort, and the `LIMIT` is folded in.  Otherwise, *all* the rows (after filtering) are written to a temp table, sorted, *then* 10 rows are peeled off.

The "temp table" I just mentioned is necessary for various complex queries, such as those with subqueries, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`.  (As I have already hinted, *sometimes* the temp table can be avoided.)  Anyway, the temp table comes in 2 flavors:  `MEMORY` and `MyISAM`.  `MEMORY` is favorable because it is faster.  However, `TEXT` (and several other things) prevent its use.

If `MEMORY` is used then `Using filesort` is a misnomer -- the sort is really an in-memory sort, hence quite fast.  For 10 rows (or even 100) the time taken is insignificant.